# .Net Core API allow only one user to call route at a time

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a route that needs to make sure that only one user can make that request at a time. How would I enforce that?

Answer (score 1):

Using a static boolean as a field on the controller, you can prevent execution with a guard clause. Static objects are shared across threads within a single application so this should affect all users. The volatile keyword ensures that changes are available to all the threads as soon as they're made. You may have to actually lock though, which isn't done here.

```
// Controller class field declaration.
static volatile bool executing = false; 
...
// Inside the function that should only run once regardless of the caller. 
if(!executing) { 
    executing = true;
    execute(); // this is the code you want only a single execution of, regardless of the number of requests
    executing = false:
} else {
   throw new Exception ("currently executing"); 
}
```

This is not the best way, depending on your actual needs, but should work for the minimum needs.